# HTML bold tag issue - 

Tags: android, facebook

```
String text="<b>Interesting ,"+titletext+"\n"+location+"</b>";
    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
    parameters.putString("message",Html.fromHtml(text).toString());
```

and am posting it to facebook by

```
facebookClient.request("me/feed", parameters, "POST");
```

I want the message posting should be in bold. but its not working

Any correct way to achieve this bold text to wall?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, feed posting functionality in Facebook Graph API does not support bold or italic formats in the feed.

It is only allowed to attach links, images or videos in your feed.

Comment: is it possible to send bold caption for a picture using photos.upload?

Comment: No, Facebook does not have such a display option anyway.